# React Redux Not Mapping the Action to Props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have created an action `updateChapter` to update the database. I have imported that into my component called `EditChapter`. When I logged the props for that component I don't see `updateChapter` action on that props.

I have mapped some other actions from same `Actions.js` file into some other component and those are working fine. I don't understand this case. Here is my code.

**Actions.js**

```
export const updateChapter = formData => dispatch => {
    myAxios.post('/updateChapter', formData)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

**Component File**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {updateChapter} from '../../store/chapterStore/Actions';

const EditChapter = props => {

    const {classes} = props;
    const [chapterTitle, setChapterTitle] = React.useState('');

    const updateChapterHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formState = {
            chapter_title: chapterTitle,
        }
        let formData = appendDataIntoFormData(formState);

        props.updateChapter(formData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={updateChapterHandler}>
                 <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <FormControl
                            component="fieldset"
                            fullWidth
                            margin="normal">
                            <FormLabel component="legend">
                                Chapter Title
                            </FormLabel>
                            <TextField 
                            required
                            value={chapterTitle}
                            onChange={event => setChapterTitle(event.target.value)}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
            </form>
        </div>
     );
}

const mapActionToProps = ({
    updateChapter
});

export default connect(null, mapActionToProps)(EditChapter);
```

Comment: Can you please share how you are using `updateChapter` inside `EditChapter` ?

Comment: Updated the question with usage of  `updateChapter`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code but try changing `mapActionToProps` from  `({ updateChapter });` to `{ updateChapter };` and see if it works.

Comment: still not working @usafder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but try with this:

```
    const mapActionToProps = dispatch => ({
          updateChapter: (formData) => dispatch(updateChapter(formData));
    });
```

Comment: It's working and I am accepting your answer but can you explain why was my code not working in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are using old redux way, my suggestion use the latest way of React Redux bro!!

Comment: what's the latest way of react redux. can you provide any link which explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks, it will simplify your code.

Check the documentation https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks